# How to setup a callback whenever a bearer token expires?

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

This is the [documentation](http://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc6750.html) I've read on bearer tokens.

I'am looking to setup a bearer token with a expires_in value of 1000000(~11 days) but store and use this token in AWS Secrets Manager - https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Right now the process isn't automated. Every 11 days, I have to go and manually update AWS Secrets Manager with the new token value. I'am looking to automate this and setup a callback. Whenever the token expires, I want to update AWS Secrets Manager via [update secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/update-secret.html) with the a bearer token.

Does anyone have any references to any code samples I could use for this? I was thinking I could use AWS Lambda to make the actual calls to update the secret in Secrets Manager but I'am not sure how to write the trigger for the lambda

The function callable from the docs didn't have a parameter for specifying a callback function(for use when the token has expired)